# Adding streaming video file from rtsp link to my website

Tags: html, google-chrome, mozilla, rtsp, wmv

Here is my code. It works fine in all browsers on my computer,but it doesn't work on another.

Info

- The video file is in .wmv format
- It shows alert like `install activex plugin`.
- After clicking the install button it shows errors.
- It works fine in internet explorer but fails in mozilla and chrome.
- I think it may because of the browser doesn't have the plugin.

Questions

- Is there any other way to supports this in all browsers?
- Is there any way to install those plugins by code?

  ```
  <object
  codebase="http://www.microsoft.com/Windows/MediaPlayer/" height="360" width="480">
  <param name="Filename" value="rtsp://xyz.wmv" />
  <param name="AutoStart" value="true" />
  <param name="ShowControls" value="true" />
  <param name="BufferingTime" value="2" />
  <param name="ShowStatusBar" value="true" />
  <param name="AutoSize" value="true" />
  <param name="InvokeURLs" value="false" />
  <embed autostart="1" codebase="http://activex.microsoft.com/activex
  /controls/mplayer/en/nsmp2inf.cab#Version=6,0,0,0" 
  enabled="1" height="360" pluginspage="http://www.microsoft.com/Windows/MediaPlayer/" 
  showcontrols="1" showdisplay="1" 
  showstatusbar="1" src="rtsp://xyz.wmv" type="application/x-mplayer2" width="480">
  </embed>
  </object>
  ```

Comment: you could get the video in a .mp4 filetype and then just use the `<video>` tag and embed it using HTML5 natively.

Comment: k thanks .i will do...

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to go the route of converting to an .mp4 filetype using the `<video>` tag here is the code you would use. Just replace the `src` with your own.

```
<video width="480" height="360" controls>
  <source src="YOURMOVIE.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  VIDEO
</video>
```